# allow user to add new items to a combobox C#

Tags: c#

I have a combobox, and I need to allow user to add new items to this combobox in a way that the new added item will be there every time I run the application. Can you suggest methods for me?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Items>
  <Items>
    <Company>wd</Company>
    <Fluid>dswq</Fluid>
    <Price>qw</Price>
  </Items>
</Items>
```

Comment: Store the new added combobox item in the file or database, and load combobox items from this file (or database) every time you run the app

Comment: I'm thinking this way and I am trying xml file but I don't know how to use it if you can help. @MikhailNeofitov

Comment: SO is not a coding service, try to search how to work with xml and come back, if you will have problems with it.

Comment: see my edit, I have created the xml file dynamically, and what i want now is to fill a combobox called cbCompany from the <Company> and the same thing for Fluid and Price, but I didn't understand how to append elements @MikhailNeofitov

Answer (score 1):

you can check out [akavache](https://github.com/akavache/Akavache). It's persistent key-value cache based on SQLite3 database. Works great for me.

On plus side, you can decide whether saved values will saved per-user or per-machine, and it is superfast.

Then you can just bind ObservableCollection to you combobox ItemsSource and add saved items in a loop.

Comment: Thank you I will look at that @user3512524

Comment: It also can encrypt you data. You can put xml into the cache, or akavache will try to serialize it for you. Make sure to allow that

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with using a text file (not encrypted, accessible by anyone, etc.) Here is quick form that does just what you asked for.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string[] options;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            initTextBox();
        }

        private void initTextBox()
        {

            try
            {
                options = File.ReadAllLines("input.txt");
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
            {
                File.CreateText("input.txt").Close();

                options = File.ReadAllLines("input.txt");
            }
            if (options.Length == 0) return;
            foreach (var item in options)
            {
                comboBox.Items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        private void button_addItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            comboBox.Items.Add(textBox_newItem.Text);
            File.WriteAllLines("input.txt", options);
        }
    }
```

If you want a more secure version, replace the File I/O with database I/O as others suggested.

Comment: I prefer xml because I'm dealing with three comboboxes

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693072.aspx
This link should have all the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, this is just a simple representation to your question:

First load your file to a XDocument:

```
var xml = XDocument.Load("D:\\temp.xml");
```

Then load it to a anonymous type as a list:

```
 var studentLst = xml.Descendants("Items").Select(d =>
 new
 {
   Company = d.Element("Company").Value,
   Fluid = d.Element("Fluid").Value,
   Price = d.Element("Price").Value
}).ToList();
```

Then select what property you want to bind to your Combobox (on this case, I choose Company):

```
comboBox1.DataSource = studentLst.Select(x => x.Company).ToList();
```

P.S. This is the format of my XML File (I made the first node as 'Item' so that I can see all 'Items' node):

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Item>
  <Items>
     <Company>wd</Company>
     <Fluid>dswq</Fluid>
     <Price>qw</Price>
  </Items>
</Item>
```